# Get new c# guid into javascript function using razor in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I have js function:

```
function getGuid(){
    var guid = '@Guid.NewGuid()';
    return guid;
}
```

But every time I execute this function I get 1 constant value. Is there a way to rerender guid or it's better to write generating guid into plain javascript?

Comment: Live streaming https://xkcd.com/221/  :) ....

Comment: You'll have to generate the GUID in js. The only way to get it from C# (which wouldn't really offer a benefit) would be to make an AJAX call to a GUID-generating endpoint of your API.